# Standardizing data structures between different platforms

Tags: data-structures, structure, frontend, standards, backend

Imagine, for example, you have front-end and back-end applications. They are both written in different technologies, lets say backend is in python using django and front end in typescript using angular.

Now there will be some data that will need to be shared between those two. Enums, serialized dictionaries of class instances or names of some fields.

Very quickly a problem arises of data structure duplication and possibility of desynchronisation. (E.g. you have to have to exact enums on both platforms)

I was wondering are there any "best practices" out there?
Like XML based standardizing data or something?

Could you point me to some books / articles?
Could you share your knowledge of how you do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are best practices for sharing data. XML is one. Another is JSON. There are many variants. Do a little research into serialization technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to solve this obstacle:

- Write your own clients for consumers.
- Use model contracts like [RAML](https://raml.org/) and generate models from declarations.

And you don't have to have the same exact enum or any other class on both platforms. There should be a layer that consumes and returns any data to the outside world(external client). This layer has its own models. Everything that lies below should have their own. You can have many small objects stored in database, but return to the client huge aggregates and that would be different models. Read about data models in standard N-tier application.